# mySQL base authentication error in express framework

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Recently I put my interest in node.js and learned a great about it and quickly move to the express framework. I've tried to connect my express application with mysql database and succeeded. Now I try to authenticate a simple login from connected with mysql database but I can't do that. Still don't get it why it is happening. Bellow here is the code I've used. A help will be greatly welcome.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'express_db',
    password: '12345'
});
connection.connect();


exports.admin_login = function (req, res) {
    res.render('./admin/login', {title: 'Please provide your credentials to login'});
};


exports.admin_home = function (req, res) {
    var parse = req.body;
    var name = parse.name;
    var password = parse.password;
    var sql = "select * from user where name = " + connection.escape(name) + " and     password = " + connection.escape(password);
    connection.query(sql, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (name == results[0].name && password == results[0].password) {
            req.session.regenerate(function () {
                req.session.name = results[0].id;
                res.render('./admin/home', {username: results[0].name});
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What happens to your application? Does it hang or does err get thrown?

Comment: **Don't store passwords in plain text**.  Instead, use bcrypt.

Comment: SLaks, the issue is not about storing password into plain text. What I want to do is from the login form I need to compare the username and password with the user table. If it matches then I'll store the user id into session. If I get success I can encrypt the password later. See, password encryption is not the issue I'm pointing.   @jbarnett the node server throws and error.